# Good practice - throw an exception to satisfy a function return

Tags: c#, error-handling, return

Built a custom IDataReader which goes looking in XML for values that match particular element names and, if found, returns the values. The GetValue function - which has to return an Object, as specified by the interface, looks like this:

```
    public object GetValue(int i)
    {
        string SearchString = _columns[i];

        var searchedAttributeValue = from nm in _el.Attributes(SearchString) select nm;
        if (searchedAttributeValue.Count() > 0)
        {
            return ParseTypes(searchedAttributeValue.First().Value);
        }

        var searchedElementValue = from nm in _el.Elements(SearchString) select nm;
        if (searchedElementValue.Count() > 0)
        {
            return ParseTypes(searchedElementValue.First().Value);
        }
    }
```

This won't build, obviously, because it's possible to reach the end of the function without a valid return.

In this instance, if that happens, it means there's a config error - the user is looking for an element or attribute in the XML that's not there.

I discovered (this was new to me) that you can get round the problem by doing this:

```
    public object GetValue(int i)
    {
        if (_el == null)
        {
            _el = XNode.ReadFrom(_reader) as XElement;
        }
        string SearchString = _columns[i];

        var searchedAttributeValue = from nm in _el.Attributes(SearchString) select nm;
        if (searchedAttributeValue.Count() > 0)
        {
            return ParseTypes(searchedAttributeValue.First().Value);
        }

        var searchedElementValue = from nm in _el.Elements(SearchString) select nm;
        if (searchedElementValue.Count() > 0)
        {
            return ParseTypes(searchedElementValue.First().Value);
        }

        throw new Exception("oh crap!");
    }
```

So the function doesn't return, it just throws an error.

However, something feels fundamentally wrong with this approach. Is it okay, why is it okay/not okay and is there a better way to handle the situation?

Comment: Why not just return null? After all, is the parser not able to parse something truly exceptional behavior?

Comment: If you're going to throw, why are you throwing in `finally`, rather than just at the end of the function? That seems unnecessarily confusing and possibly wrong. Isn't `finally` also executed for the normal returns?

Comment: @svk Yes, just realised that and edited accordingly

Comment: Couldn't help myself - looking at your screen name, I can imagine why you prefer this approach :)

Comment: @matt-dillard Yes, sorry, see above. Being an eejit :)

Comment: By the by, `searchedElementValue.Count() > 0` can be replaced by `searchedElementValue.Any()` and 1) be more telling on what you are wanting and 2) possibly be more performant.

Comment: And, of course, Jon Skeet makes a better case with `.FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: for info, Matt - I have a fully worked IDataReader example that I was preparing for your now-deleted question - just in case you find it useful: http://pastie.org/8479748

Comment: @marc-gravell Thank you. I apologise for the repeated delete questions - struggling to understand how the internals of this process work. I keep stumbling on answers by accident rather than design, things which function but don't advance my understanding. Makes it hard to frame the right questions.

Comment: @MattThrower hopefully that complete example will help you figure out which cog is falling out...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well unless you really *need* the `catch` block, you don't need to introduce try/catch/finally. You can just add a `throw` statement at the end of your initial method.

Along the way, I'd start using `FirstOrDefault()`, follow normal C# naming conventions for local variables, stop using query expressions when they're not terribly useful, and throw a more specific exception:

```
public object GetValue(int i)
{
    string searchString = _columns[i];

    var searchedAttribute = _el.Attributes(searchString).FirstOrDefault();
    if (searchedAttribute != null)
    {
        return ParseTypes(searchedAttribute.Value);
    }

    var searchedElement = _el.Elements(searchString).FirstOrDefault();
    if (searchedElement != null)
    {
        return ParseTypes(searchedElement.Value);
    }
    // Nothing found - oops.
    throw new SomeSpecificException("Some message here");
}
```

If you need the catch block for logging, I'd probably try to catch a *specific* exception, which probably means moving that into `ParseTypes` anyway (as you shouldn't get any exceptions from the rest of the calls...) Either way, keep the `throw` statement at the end.

EDIT: In terms of design, whether you should throw an exception when the value isn't found or not really depends on the expectations. We have no way of knowing whether that indicates something wrong with the system, or just a perfectly normal absence of data. That should determine your choice here. In particular, if every caller is going to try to catch the exception, then that's a design smell and you should either return `null` or use something like the `Dictionary<,>.TryGetValue` approach.

Comment: Thanks - very helpful. The question remains - is it better to throw an exception or return null?

Comment: My bad, since I framed the question poorly in the first place, meaning early answers were less useful. Sorry :( Thank you both for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

I like to make my methods similar to the .NET framework Parse() and TryParse() methods. In your case I would either do:

```
public object GetValue(int i)
{
    // ...

    // fail
    throw new Exception("Cannot get value");
}
```

or do:

```
public bool TryGetValue(int i, out object result)
{
    // ...

    // fail
    result = null;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The try catch is irrelvant. you could simply refactor your code to:

```
public object GetValue(int i)
{

   if (_el == null)
   {
      _el = XNode.ReadFrom(_reader) as XElement;
   }
     string SearchString = _columns[i];

   var searchedAttributeValue = from nm in _el.Attributes(SearchString) select nm;
   if (searchedAttributeValue.Count() > 0)
   {
      return ParseTypes(searchedAttributeValue.First().Value);
   }

   var searchedElementValue = from nm in _el.Elements(SearchString) select nm;
   if (searchedElementValue.Count() > 0)
   {
      return ParseTypes(searchedElementValue.First().Value);
   }

   throw new Exception("oh crap!");
}
```

this has the same net result.

---

That said throwing exceptions are expensive (computationaly). If you want this to bomb out (stop processing completly, this is a major problem and it should simply die) then thrown an exception.

If it's simply a way to identify when the `if` statements are not being met maybe change it to a `TryParse` type function:

```
public bool GetValue(int i, out object returnVal)
{

   if (_el == null)
   {
      _el = XNode.ReadFrom(_reader) as XElement;
   }
     string SearchString = _columns[i];

   var searchedAttributeValue = from nm in _el.Attributes(SearchString) select nm;
   if (searchedAttributeValue.Count() > 0)
   {
      returnVal = ParseTypes(searchedAttributeValue.First().Value);
      return true;
   }

   var searchedElementValue = from nm in _el.Elements(SearchString) select nm;
   if (searchedElementValue.Count() > 0)
   {
      returnVal = ParseTypes(searchedElementValue.First().Value);
      return true;
   }

   return false;
}
```

then

```
if (GetValue(i, out value))
   //success
else
   //it's failed.
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is genuinely an exceptional circumstance that the search won't return anything because the configuration is wrong, then by all means, throw an exception. The problem with this is continuation. Can client code continue if an item isn't found? If it can, client code will need to closely examine any exception thrown from your code to determine if it was thrown because an item didn't exist, or because something else went wrong that can't be continued from.

The other option is to return something that indicates that the value wasn't found, and allow calling code to deal with it. You could return `null` to indicate to calling code that no item was found, and that might be fine in this instance. A better solution might be to create a simple `Optional<T>` class, that contains an indication of whether the object existed (perhaps `HasValue`), and the object itself if it did. Calling code can easily and more concretely check whether an object was returned and deal with a situation where it isn't, and exceptions don't require additional scrutiny.

EDIT: A better alternative altogether might be the `Parse` and `TryParse` paradigm suggested by others, but I think this answer might have some use, so I'll leave it here :)

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few bad practices in this approach: `catch (Exception)` should always be avoided. Only catch the exceptions you expect there. Also, `throw Exception()` is bad style. Always throw something more specific. But for what you're looking for: You don't need a finally after all, just place a `throw new ArgumentException()` or something as the last line of the function. That is good practice, if it is really a programming error if the code ever runs there.